# Вставить текст в border CSS HTML

Tags: css, html5, text, background, border

Мне нужно вставить текст по центру в верхнюю и нижнюю  границу, которые будут иметь фоновое изображение позади них. Это будет  на каждой странице. Я могу добиться этого с помощью `CSS`?

Пожалуйста, посмотрите скриншот того, что я имею в виду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Граница должна быть белого цвета, 3 пикселя в ширину, а шрифт - `Basis Grotesque Medium`.

Я надеюсь начать с редактирования темы `WordPress`.

Надеюсь, что на этот вопрос не был получен ответ в другом месте. Я пытался искать, но не мог найти то, что мне нужно.

Прежде чем  идти вперед и начать строить этот сайт, не могли бы вы сказать мне, если это возможно,  как я могу  достигнуть этого?

Источник: [Insert text in border CSS HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164342/insert-text-in-border-css-html/30164520#30164520)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164342/insert-text-in-border-css-html/30164520#30164520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавлю свои 5 копеек...

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1016956/27ec7a52-f169-49d8-b895-10a84386bb8b/s1200);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

fieldset {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: white;
}

fieldset+fieldset {
  transform: rotatex(180deg);
}

fieldset+fieldset>legend {
  transform: rotatex(180deg);
}

fieldset>p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Lorem</legend>
  <p>...content...</p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Ipsum</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_T да ради бога...

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать тот подход, который я описал здесь - [Line separator under text and transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-before-and-after-title-over-image) - на линии слева/справа от названия.

Затем вы можете использовать отрицательные поля `top/bottom margin`, и расположите их на нижней и верхней границах :

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
 body {
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1016956/27ec7a52-f169-49d8-b895-10a84386bb8b/s1200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
}
#content{
  border:3px solid #fff;
  border-width:0 3px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:50px 0;
  width:100%;
}
.divider {
  font-size:30px;
  margin: -0.65em auto -0.45em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.divider:before,
.divider:after {
  content: "";
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0.65em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  margin: 0 2% 0 -55%;
}
.divider:after {
  margin: 0 -55% 0 2%;
}
p{margin: 150px 0;}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="divider">Top title</h1>
  <p>...Content here...</p>
  <h2 class="divider">Bottom title</h2>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что `top/bottom negative margins` потребуют тонкую настройку  семейства шрифтов, которые вы используете.